# auth/invalid-credential in firebase auth with expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to do email password auth with firebase but keep getting this:

> ERROR  [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-credential).]

**I have the firebase config properly setup and also this:**

```
const app = getApps.length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});

export { auth };
```

but when i reach this point:

```
import { auth } from "../../../firebaseConfig";

const cred = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            email,
            password
          );
```

I am getting invalid-credential when I should be getting "auth/user-not-found"

This is a react native app with "firebase": "^10.7.0" with expo sdk 49. I have correct firebase config.

Answer (score 1):

The response `auth/user-not-found` can be used by malicious users to find out what users exist in your project, by repeatedly calling it. This is known as an email enumeration attack and on projects created since September 15, Firebase automatically protects against such attacks. See the documentation on [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) for full details.

For the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` API that you call, this protection against email enumeration attacks works by returning a more generic error code than the one you're looking for. This is the only way to prevent malicious users from being able to abuse that API to put your users at risk.

You can either handle the new, more generic error code - or you can [disable email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable).